# Creating a connection to ESB ( Web Logic, connection factory) java

Tags: java, connection, jms, weblogic

I just started and I want to create a program in java that can connect to ESB. I have been doing research and 'connection factory' keeps cropping up as a default object that creates the connection. I'm still a bit confused and would appreciate it if someone could explain what the purpose of connection factory is and how it is created - having a tough time understanding. Would also appreciate links/tutorials that i could look at.

Answer (score 0):

Connection factories are objects that enable JMS clients to create JMS connections. A connection factory supports concurrent use, enabling multiple threads to access the object simultaneously. Weblogic provides a default connection factory but if it doesn't suit your need, say for something like high throughput, you can create your own.

This is an excellent tutorial: http://oraclesoaandoim.blogspot.com/2012/01/weblogic-1035-create-connection.html

Another solid JMS tutorial: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6334

Weblogic documentation on JMS here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/jms/implement.html